# JavaScript Nested Object Deconstruction "Cannot read properties of null" with default value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to deconstruct an object in JavaScript. I've assigned default values in the deconstruction but I'm still getting the following error:

`React Router caught the following error during render TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'responseTimePoints')`

This is my deconstruction code:

```
    const testRun = useTestRunModel();

    const {
        id: testRunId,
        graphData: { responseTimePoints = [] } = {},
    } = testRun || {};
```

This is the output of the `testRun` object:
[image: Code output]

Essentially, I'd like `responseTimePoints` to be set to an empty array in the event that `testRun` / `testrun.graphData` / `testRun.graphData.responseTimePoints` are null or undefined.

I'm not sure if it matters, but I am using React 18.2 with TypeScript 5.1.6, and this is my tsconfig.json:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es2015",
    "allowJs": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "types": []
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default initialisers in destructuring (and function parameters) only apply when the value is `undefined` (or the property/argument is absent altogether), not when it is `null`

Use nullish coalescing instead:

```
const testRun = useTestRunModel();

const testRunId = testRun?.id;
const responseTimePoints = testRun?.graphData?.responseTimePoints ?? [];
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I thought it'd work if the value was null OR undefined. 

Got it working. Thank you.